# How do I use the result of fetch() multiple time without it becoming undefined? (new to JS)

Tags: javascript, promise, fetch

I have some basic code that uses fetch() to get a json from an api. Then I "sort" (idk if thats the right word) through the "layers" (again don't know the word) to get (for example) the number of kills they have gotten in a certain gamemode on a minecraft server. The problem is I would like to check another stat, for example games played. I can't just get the data from the api again because you can only get data on each player once per minute. The problem is when I try to use the result from the fetch() again it doesn't work as the promise has been fulfilled I think (I am really new to Java Script). Here is the code:

```
<body>
    <form>
        <label for="fname">Username:</label><br>
        <input type="text" id="username" name="username"><br>
    </form>

    <p class="costs" id="kills">Hello!</p>

    <script>
        function BedwarsKills() {
            var queryString = location.search; // Returns:'?q=123'
            let params = new URLSearchParams(queryString);
            let q = params.get("username"); // is the number 123
            console.log(q)

            url = "https://api.hypixel.net/player?name="+q+"&key=d3a8fade-b2e6-4a3b-8239-e11a1c9a52d4"
            console.log(url)
            fetch(url)
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(data => data.player.stats.Bedwars.kills_bedwars)
                .then(data => document.getElementById("kills").innerHTML = q + " has " + data + " kills")
        }
        BedwarsKills()
    </script>       
</body>
```

Just to clarify I would like to add something else like these 2 lines

```
                .then(data => data.player.stats.Bedwars.kills_bedwars)
                .then(data => document.getElementById("kills").innerHTML = q + " has " + data + " kills")
```

but using wins_bedwars in the place of kills_bedwars using the same fetch thing. Any ideas?

(let me know if you need to know anything else)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use two `.then()` calls for synchronous functions. You can achieve the same with a single callback function and a local variable:

```
fetch(url)
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => {
     const kills = data.player.stats.Bedwars.kills_bedwars;
     document.getElementById("kills").innerHTML = q + " has " + kills + " kills");
});
```

You can easily put multiple statements in the function - as many as you want, including some for `wins_bedwars` in addition to those for `kills_bedwars`.

Answer (score 0):

Since Promise chain is a kind of pipeline, so you should put all the data into the pipeline at a time, like:

```
        fetch(url)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => data.player.stats.Bedwars)
            .then(data => {
               document.getElementById("kills").innerHTML = q + " has " + data.kills_bedwars + " kills");
               document.getElementById("wins").innerHTML = q + " has " + data.wins_bedwars + " wins");
            });
```